# How can I complete "The Elder Knowledge"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was working on the main quest in skyrim involving the dragons and I made it to the part of the quest called "The Elder Knowledge" only to find that due to the fact that I had previously done the quest with the lexicon beforehand I can no longer complete the main quest. Does anybody know of any way to get around this? If so it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm sure it would be a simple fix if I were playing on PC, as there is probably some form of code or something I could enter into the console, but unfortuantely I am playing on a console. Any assistance given would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There are two different lexicons for two separate quests. I know this because I had both on me at the same time. One you get from the docks of Riften and it already contains information and you are asked to return it. Completely, 100% unrelated, except that it is also called a Lexicon, is the one you do for the Elder Knowledge quest. That one starts out blank and needs to have information imprinted upon it.

So, not a bug, just the way it goes, and technically if you already did this some how then you should already have the Elder Scroll, or you left it behind and can just go get it again.

Comment: +1, except you cannot remove the lexicon from your inventory (it's essential)

Comment: @JuanManuel They go away when you use them in the quests at the appropriate locations, one to the machine then crazy guy, the other back to its resting spot in the dungeon.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry.